# REST Server: Mojolicious truncating stash values

Tags: perl, rest, mojolicious

I'm fairly new to Mojolicious and creating REST services. I am trying to write a REST service to query an asset database.

An example URL:

http://test.example.com:3000/test/asset/web01.example.local

That gets routed to the following logic:

```
get '/test/asset/:node' => sub {
        my $self  = shift;
        my $node = $self->stash('node');
        my $sql = qq {
            SELECT id, name, type, location 
            FROM inventory 
            WHERE name = ?
        };
        my $cursor = $self->db->prepare($sql);
        $cursor->execute($node,$node);
        my $record = $cursor->fetchrow_hashref;
        $cursor->finish;
        $self->db_disconnect;

        say $self->stash('node');
        return $self->render(json => $record);
};
```

The "say" statement reveals that .example.local is being truncated:

---

```
[Wed Aug 27 21:24:05 2014] [debug] GET "/test/asset/web01.example.local".
[Wed Aug 27 21:24:05 2014] [debug] Routing to a callback. 
web01
[Wed Aug 27 21:24:05 2014] [debug] 200 OK (0.004076s, 245.339/s).
```

---

How do I get my service to accept an string what contains dot's it? If this is not possible, what would be a way I can use a GET request and pass an FQDN (The only thing I can use to query 2 independent DB's) and return a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to change the type of place-holder from *generic* to *relaxed*.

```
get '/test/asset/*node' => sub {
   # your sub continues here ...
```

See also the [Mojolicious Guide Routing](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Wildcard-placeholders)

Comment: I was digging through Mojo and was looking in the Controller module as that is where the stash module appeared to live. Thanks for the info.